# How can dividend protection be considered in the binomial model in pricing the convertible bond?

Tags: convertible-bond

If the convertible bond has dividend-protection, how can we cater it in the binomial model?

If there is dividend protection at or above 1%, can we impose input of dividend yield of 1% in the binomial model/Monte-Carlo simulation? If so, is there any reference to explain such method? Thanks.